# Parsing XML in xcode

Tags: xml, xcode, nsxmlparser

How can i Parse this xml in Xcode. Its urgent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<url>
    <string name="address">SomeValue</string>
</url>
```

Comment: Using XMLParser and implement those 2 or 3 delegates like begin and end...

Comment: tried anything???? try this https://www.google.co.in/search?q=xml+parsing+%2B+xcode&aq=f&oq=xml+parsing+%2B+xcode&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.5308&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Please look at this [link][1] it may help you 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733286/nsxmlparser-with-multiple-attributes

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSXMLParser on the iPhone, how do i use it given a xml file (newb here :\‌)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964503/nsxmlparser-on-the-iphone-how-do-i-use-it-given-a-xml-file-newb-here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following code, it might help you :)

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
       attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"string"])
            urlStr = [[NSString alloc] init];

    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
        if(!currentElementValue)
            currentElementValue = [[NSString alloc] init];

        currentElementValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string];
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    {
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"string"])
           urlStr = [NSString stringWithString:currentElementValue];

    }

    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    }
```